# write float list to csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of float numbers, its format is:

```
float_list = [1.13, 0.25, 3.28, ....]
```

I used following code to write it to a .csv file:

```
float_str = ""

for result in result_list:
    float_str = float_str + str(result.get_value()) + ","

with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(float_str)

file.close()
```

where `result.get_value()` is:

```
def get_value():
    return float(value)
```

I expect to see that in each cell, there is a value. However, what I've got looks like:

```
1   .   1   3   ,    0   .   2    5   ,  3   .   2   8   ,
```

It seems that each of the digits occupies a cell.

So, may I know how can I solve this issue and get what I expected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `writer.writerow()` takes a *sequence* (a list or tuple), but you are passing in a string instead. By passing in a string, `writer.writerow()` still treats it as as sequence, and each individual character becomes a column value:

```
1,.,1,3,,,0,.,2,5,,,3,.,2,8
```

Moreover, the method converts column to strings *for you*, don't do this yourself.

Instead build a list of your float values and pass that in:

```
row = []
for result in result_list:
    row.append(result.get_value())

with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(row)
```

or even:

```
with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow([r.get_value() for r in result_list])
```

The delimiter defaults to `,`.

Comment: You say you don't need to do the conversion, but leave in the example any? I think the whole `row` thing here is redundant... `writer.writerow(result_list)` (going by OP's `get_value()`)

Comment: @JonClements: Then at the very least `writer.writer([r.get_value() for r in result_list])` is required.

Answer (score 6):

Use `delimiter` and just write the list you don't need to convert it to string:

```
import csv

float_list = [1.13, 0.25, 3.28]

with open(output_path, "wb") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(float_list)
```

Output:

> 1.13,0.25,3.28

Also there is **no need** to close the file since you used `with`

**Edit:**

@Martijn Pieters: delimiter `,` is default.

From [Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter):

> A one-character string used to separate fields. It defaults to ','.

This line `writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')` can be `writer = csv.writer(file)`

Comment: `delimiter=','` is the default.

Answer (score 4):

I just want to write a number, like 1234,  into csv file (`delimiter=' '`), it ends up like 1 2 3 4. 
I got the following answer from another site but would like to share it here:

```
number = 1.13
writer.writerow([number])
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code writes a list of float numbers into a csv file.

```
import csv

float_str=['1.500','2.48933','7.36945']

with open('output_path','w',newline='') as file:

    write=csv.writer(file, delimiter='\n')
    for num in float_str:
        write.writerow(num)
```

Comment: This is just wrong, at least try out your code before you post it. Also it doesn't add anything to the other answers.

Comment: It adds `delimiter = \n` which is best for exporting data into column format